# merge / synchronize data frame using pandas

Tags: pandas, merge, synchronization

merge / synchronize 2 dataframes

`dfA = {1.0001, 1.0003, 1.0005, 1.0007, 1.0009} # timestamp A dfB = {1.0002, 1.0004, 1.0006, 1.0008, 1.0010} # timestamp B`

can we merge / synchrozie to something like this :
`dfAB = {1.0001, 1.0002, 1.0003, 1.0004, 1.0005, 1.0006, 1.0007, 1.0008, 1.0009, 1.0010}`
Assuming the values are timestamps in secs

Any pointers would help

Thanks in Advanced

**NOTE**: **i have tried pd.merge but the result** **i get is**
`dfAB = {1.0001, 1.0003, 1.0005, 1.0007, 1.0009,1.0002, 1.0004, 1.0006, 1.0008, 1.0010 }`

Comment: So need sort column?

Comment: `pd.concat([dfA, dfB])`